# Как заполнить массив рекурсивно

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
arr=[]
function recurArray(startIndex,endindex,data){  
    if(startIndex==endindex){
        return arr;
    }else{
        startIndex++;   
        arr.push(data[startIndex]);
        recurArray(startIndex,endindex);
    } 
}
recurArray(0,10,[1,2,3])
console.log(arr)// выдает Cannot read property '2' of undefined 
                //а должно быть [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]......[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Увы, рекурсия здесь не нужна. Используйте циклы.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, они в принципе взаимозаменяемы :)

Comment: @Grundy, только в принципе. Рекурсивный вызов вполне может переполнить стек. Ну и лепить костыль там, где это не нужно - плохая практика

Comment: @DmitriySimushev **на практике** нет, но это и не похоже на практическую задачу. Хотя предупреждение действительно не помешает.

Comment: @Кнопкатык, **на практике** - эта задача решается через цикл. А если искусственные ограничения существенны (лабораторка, экзамен, собеседование) то стоит выделить из вопроса часть "по существу". Сейчас это сеанс дистанционной отладки с выявлением пропущенного аргумента.

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле, вам не нужна рекурсия. Совсем. Да, кто-то может сказать, что рекурсия вполне заменяет циклы. Но он будет с вами не до конца честен.

Реализация рекурсивных вызовов в JavaScript (как и во многих других языках) предполагает создание стека вызовов. При слишком большой глубине рекурсии (в вашем случае слишком большом количестве элементов) может произойти переполнение стека (*тот самый StackOverflow*). Ситуацию могла бы исправить оптимизация [хвостовой рекурсии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F), являющаяся частью ES6, но из основных сред выполнения JS ее никто не [поддерживает](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-proper_tail_calls_%28tail_call_optimisation%29).

При использовании циклов, таких проблем у вас не возникнет.

---

Приведу красивый способ решить вашу конкретную задачу встроенными средствами языка:

```
var arr = (new Array(10)).fill([1,2,3]);
console.log(arr);
```

А для четкого следования условию задачи можно использовать вот такую функцию:

```
var fillArray = function(startIndex, endIndex, value) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
        res[i] = value;
    }

    return res;
}

console.log(fillArray(0, 10, [1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: В каком месте тут ответ на вопрос? А предложенный код заполняет весь массив, а не значения от `startIndex` до `endindex`. Что, минус ставить?

Comment: @Qwertiy, `(new Array(10))` создает массив емкостью в 10(эквивалент `endIndex - startIndex`). Аргумент `startIndex` - считаю костылем, необходимым для построения рекурентного наполнителя. Ну и мой ответ сводится не к куску копипасты, а на попытку убедить ТС в том, что рекурсия не нужна. А что касается минусов -- я спокойно к ним отношусь. Тем более к неадекватным.

Comment: Убедить того, кто делает домашку на рекурсию, что рекурсия не нужна? Ну да, логично.

Comment: @Qwertiy, заодно обновил ответ, приведя реализацию функции из условия на циклах. Ведь ответ без копапасты лишен всякого смысла, не правда ли?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я отвечаю не только и не столько на вопрос ТС (он сводится к дистанционной отладке и поиску пропущенного аргумента). Мой ответ адресован тем, кому действительно интересно как рекурсия соотносится с циклами.

Answer (score 1):

В вызове `recurArray(startIndex,endindex)` не передается параметр `data`, поэтому внутри вызова он равен *undefined*

Кроме того, судя по ожидаемому результату в строку

```
arr.push(data[startIndex]);
```

нужно заменить на

```
arr.push(data);
```

Да и стоит убрать зависимость от внешней переменной:

```js
function recurArray(startIndex, endindex, data) {
  if (startIndex == endindex) {
    return [data];
  } else {
    return [data].concat(recurArray(startIndex + 1, endindex, data));
  }
}
arr = recurArray(0, 10, [1, 2, 3]);
document.write(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr=[];
    function recurArray(startIndex,endindex,data){
        if(startIndex==endindex){
            return arr;
        }else{
            startIndex++;
            arr.push(data);
            recurArray(startIndex,endindex,data);
        }
    }
recurArray(0,10,[1,2,3])
document.write(JSON.stringify(arr))
```